# How to get different cfg and queries from another notebook in databricks

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks, azure-databricks, databricks-sql

So I am working with Azure Databricks.

I have this notebook with the following structure:

-> cfg_dic for query 1 (something like cfg_1 = {"schema":"schema", ...}

-> query 1 (something like query_1 = """SELECT * FROM ... """)

-> cfg_dic for query 2

-> query 2

and so on...

Then, I would like to have this generic notebook that has functions (I already made them):

-> to replace the config dictionary on the query

-> and another function write the query to the table that I want

my question is how do I call the cfg's and queries? I want this process to be automatic, in a sense that this generic notebook goes to the another notebook and knows which pairs of cfg and queries to use, then it goes throught the functions and executes the queries!

i think doing it like {"query_1":"cfg_1",...} could do it, but I don´t think it´s the *BEST* way of doing it!!

Thank you so much :)

UPDATE:
So what I have in this notebook is something like this:

```
cfg_1 = {"schema":"table_name_1", "prefix":_"databricks", "table":"table_1", "partitioned" : "N"}

query_1 = """ select * from {schema}{prefix} """

cfg_2 ={"schema" : "table_name_2",
        "prefix" : "_databricks",
        "table":"table_2",
        "partitioned" : 'N'}

query_2 = """ select * from {schema}{prefix} """
```

So I have 2 notebooks: notebook 1 that has the structure shown above.
And I have notebook 2 that has functions to delete and write data in those queries.
My question is: i would like to have something like dbuilts widgets, where in notebook 2 I select that I want to create "table_1" and the notebook knows which query and cfg file to get so that that query and cfg file enters the function that I have to create a new table!

I don´t know if I was a lot of messy explaining it! Sorry english is not my first language :/

Comment: hi @Inês Silva, could you provide full code `cfg_1` schema and `query_1`

Comment: and also provide more information about what you are expecting.

Comment: hi! @SaiVamsi I just updated the post!! :)